# Server programming with Clojure

Tags: concurrency, clojure

How to implement 10k connections echo server in Clojure?

clojure.contrib.server-socket is not the answer since it crates a new OS thread for every connection.

Comment: Are you referring to the c10k problem? http://www.kegel.com/c10k.html

Comment: I read it, yes, and I'm curious how it would be implemented in this interesting language. Note that clojure advertise its concurrency capabilities a lot.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The great thing about Clojure is you have all these great libraries out there for the JVM like [netty](http://jboss.org/netty), which are highly optimized, configurable, and well thought out. Something like this should get you going:

```
(ns netty
  (:gen-class)
  (:import
     [java.net InetSocketAddress]
     [java.util.concurrent Executors]
     [org.jboss.netty.bootstrap ServerBootstrap]
     [org.jboss.netty.channel Channels ChannelPipelineFactory
                              SimpleChannelHandler]
     [org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio NioServerSocketChannelFactory]
     [org.jboss.netty.buffer ChannelBuffers]))

(declare make-handler)

(defn start
  "Start a Netty server. Returns the pipeline."
  [port handler]
  (let [channel-factory (NioServerSocketChannelFactory.
                          (Executors/newCachedThreadPool)
                          (Executors/newCachedThreadPool))
        bootstrap (ServerBootstrap. channel-factory)
        pipeline (.getPipeline bootstrap)]
    (.addLast pipeline "handler" (make-handler))
    (.setOption bootstrap "child.tcpNoDelay", true)
    (.setOption bootstrap "child.keepAlive", true)
    (.bind bootstrap (InetSocketAddress. port))
    pipeline))

(defn make-handler
  "Returns a Netty handler."
  []
  (proxy [SimpleChannelHandler] []
    (channelConnected [ctx e]
      (let [c (.getChannel e)]
        (println "Connected:" c)))

    (channelDisconnected [ctx e]
      (let [c (.getChannel e)]
        (println "Disconnected:" c)))

    (messageReceived [ctx e]
      (let [c (.getChannel e)
            cb (.getMessage e)
            msg (.toString cb "UTF-8")]
        (println "Message:" msg "from" c)))

    (exceptionCaught
      [ctx e]
      (let [throwable (.getCause e)]
        (println "@exceptionCaught" throwable))
      (-> e .getChannel .close))))
```

Comment: Thanks! I put a simple leiningen project up for this here: https://github.com/cymen/clojure-netty

Comment: How do I send a message to this server?

Comment: @vemv I've updated the repo to use the github project to use a public netty and added an example of how to send a message to the server.