# Calling Files/readAttributes fails with "IllegalArgumentException: No matching method"

Tags: clojure

I'd like to call java.nio.file.Files/readAttributes, but doing so always fails with *No matching method*. For example:

```
user=> (java.nio.file.Files/readAttributes (-> "/etc/passwd" clojure.java.io/file .toPath) "posix:group")
CompilerException java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No matching method: readAttributes, compiling:(NO_SOURCE_PATH:1:1) 

user=> (java.lang.System/getProperty "java.version")
"1.7.0_25"
```

For a sanity check, doing the equivalent works fine from the scala repl:

```
scala> java.nio.file.Files.readAttributes((new java.io.File("/etc/passwd")).toPath, "posix:group")
res11: java.util.Map[String,Object] = {group=root}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that to call java variadic methods, you have to explicitly pass the vararg part as an array, even if you don't care about it. (see the question [Java Interop — Netty + Clojure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10918300/java-interop-netty-clojure))

The following works:

```
user=> (java.nio.file.Files/readAttributes (-> "/etc/passwd" clojure.java.io/file .toPath) "posix:group" (into-array java.nio.file.LinkOption []))
{"group" #<Group root>}
```

Comment: years later, this solved a bizarre problem of mine, thank you!